# Java project shows different number of processes under windows and linux

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, profiling

I wrote a client server java project using Netbeans on Windows platform. When I profile it on windows it shows 8 threads running but when I run it on Ubuntu, `htop` shows 21 processes(threads) attached to it. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The numbers mean different things. In Windows there are [process and threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In contrast, Linux uses a 1-1 threading model.

Comment: I profiled it under `Ubuntu` using `NetBeans` and the number of threads shown in both operating systems were identical. But I would like to make sense of what is shown in `Netbeans Profiler` versus what you see by utility programs such as `htop`.

Comment: Netbeans is pure Java and is reporting Java threads. Linux implements threads with processes.